# Trying to create a new dataframe based on data of another dataframe's columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new dataframe based on existing dataframe's data, I have the following data frame:
[image: existing dataframe]

And I need to create a new dataframe which sums the amount of workers joined each department every year.

I've tried the following:

```
emp_dept_sal_s[['dept_name','Year']].groupby(['dept_name','Year']).count()
```

but the output is:
[image]

**So basically, the question is how do I relative to both columns (dept_name and Year)?**
Thanks!

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

```
emp_dept_sal_s.groupby(by=['dept_name','Year']).count()
```